# plsql printing a custom object

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am having issues in printing the custom object.
Here is my complete use case

```
create or replace type invoice_obt
as object (
invoice_id number
);
/

create type invoices_ntt
as table of invoice_obt;
/

create type customer_with_invoices
as object (
customer_id number,
invoices invoices_ntt
)

declare                                                        
l_customer customer_with_invoices;                             
l_invoices invoices_ntt := invoices_ntt();                     
begin                                                          
l_invoices.extend(3);                                          
l_invoices(1) := invoice_obt(100);                             
l_invoices(2) := invoice_obt(200);                             
l_invoices(3) := invoice_obt(200);                             
l_customer := customer_with_invoices(1,l_invoices);                                                 
end;
```

How do i print out the l_customer using dbms_output please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `customer_with_invoices()`, you want to call the constructor, so you need to pass parameters for the object properties, even `null` if you want.

Also, the `extend` applies to `l_customers.invoices`, and not to `l_customers`.

For example, this works:

```
declare
    l_customers customer_with_invoices := customer_with_invoices(null, null);
begin
    l_customers.invoices := invoices_ntt();
    l_customers.invoices.extend(1);
    l_customers.invoices(1) := new invoice_obt(1);
    --
    dbms_output.put_line(l_customers.invoices(1).invoice_id);
end;
/
```

To print the content of the object with `dbms_output.put_line` , you need to pass it the elements, given that it does not handle objects. In your edited code, this is an example:

```
for i in 1 ..  l_customer.invoices.count loop
    dbms_output.put_line('invoice (' || i || ') = ' || l_customer.invoices(i).invoice_id);
end loop;
```

In a production code, you should better check if objects exist, before trying to use `.count` or similar.